# ASUS Transformer Prime Emulator in Eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to emulate my app on the ASUS Transformer Prime.

What is the max heap size on this tablet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max heap size on Transformer Prime is 48mb.